# How to select a name using foreign key, and present it on the table

Tags: php, mysql

I´m creating a school project and in this part I need to present the name of the person associated with this "n_processo" (id).
I have my tablets divided on the database like the printscreen, and I don´t know how to present the name of the person using the foreign key.

**Turma Table:**

[image]

I´m using a functions file, that have the function DBRead12 (that is selecting my "turma" table).

I have the user_especial table that have the names and the stranger key, like on this print.

**User_Especial Table:**

[image]

```
function DBRead12()
{
    $sql="SELECT * FROM turma";
    $result=DBExecute($sql);

    while($res=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $data[]=$res;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

```
<button class="collapsible">Consulta de Turmas</button>
<div class="content">
<br>
  <div class="container" align="left">
   <div class="well" align="left" style="width:70%">
     <?php $admin = DBRead12()?>
     <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:90%">
       <thead>
         <tr>
          <th>Designação</th>
      <th>Tipo</th>
      <th>Diretor de Turma</th>
      <th>Ano Letivo</th>
         </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
         <?php foreach($admin as $cl)
      {?>
     <tr> 
       <td align=center><?php echo ($cl['designacao']) ?></td>
       <td align=center><?php echo ($cl['tipo']) ?></td>
       <td align=center><?php echo ($cl['diretor_turma']) ?></td>
       <td align=center><?php echo ($cl['ano_letivo']) ?></td>
          </tr>
      <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
       </table>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query, you would use a join statement in order to get data from both tables at once

**Example:**

```
 $sql="SELECT user_especial.nome, turma.* 
          FROM turma
          LEFT JOIN user_especial ON user_especial.n_processo = turma.director_turma";
```

Comment: Ok, but on the datatable, i would need to put just the "name" of the special user? Or do something more?

Comment: No, in the query in your method, you would select the column name, and whichever foreign key you want to retrieve the data for. I updated my answer to add the id which would be the foreign key

Comment: Don´t work, I don´t know how to corret it, dind´t do something like this before... https://imgur.com/a/Kb2DI0A

Comment: Sorry, Remove the last line

Comment: But i´m selecting all the values from "turma", and it gives the foreign key "diretor_turma" that gives the ID of the person.. how can I show the name of the person instead of the ID? Because i´m using a datatable..

Comment: Have you seen the values returned in the array? this query gets everything from turma, and joins it with user_especial on the foreign key of turma

Comment: I don´t know how to solve it.. I don´t know if it is the sql or the method on the function..

Comment: I get it! On the sql the last part "turma.director_turma" it is diretor and not director. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql="SELECT user_especial.nome as nome, turma.* 
      FROM turma
      LEFT JOIN user_especial ON user_especial.n_processo = turma.director_turma";
```

This will give you all data from Turma Table and nome from User_Especial Table as nome.

Comment: Your query did not return any result, there might be problem executing query by php, query seems to return false.

Comment: I don´t know how to solve it.. I don´t know if it is the sql or the method on the function..

Comment: I get it! On the sql the last part "turma.director_turma" it is diretor and not director. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql="SELECT user_especial.nome as nome, turma.* 
          FROM turma
          LEFT JOIN user_especial ON user_especial.n_processo = turma.director_turma";
```

Also you must cut `$cl['diretor_turma']` and add `$cl['nome']`.
 So, your  tbody will be:

```
<td align=center><?php echo ($cl['designacao']) ?></td>
       <td align=center><?php echo ($cl['tipo']) ?></td>
       <td align=center><?php echo ($cl['nome']) ?></td>
       <td align=center><?php echo ($cl['ano_letivo']) ?>
</td>
```